# Which anime series was the first to be aired on Japanese TV?

Tags: anime-history

The first animated segments seem to go back all the way to 1907, and most of those older segments only got broadcast in cinemas and the likes. Even after those, most animated segments on TV consisted of short animations of roughly a few seconds.

So with that my question: Which anime *series* was the first to be aired on Japanese television? And I am asking about multi-episode series, or multi-segment series.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assumed you mean first TV series anime.

> Mighty Atom became the first popular anime television series in 1963. Contrary to popular belief, Atom was not the first anime series broadcast in Japan; that honor falls to **Otogi Manga Calendar**, which began broadcasting in 1962.

From [Otogi Manga Calendar Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otogi_Manga_Calendar)

> Otogi Manga Calendar (おとぎマンガカレンダー Otogi Manga Calendar?) was a black and white Japanese anime series aired from 1961 to 1964. It was the first anime series ever televised.

Sorry if I understood your question wrongly.

Source:
[Y!A: What was the first anime ever aired in Japan?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090529063100AANnoCt)
[Anime and Manga: Brought to You by WikiProject Anime and Manga](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=E2jHAhPXxgEC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=Mighty%20Atom%20became%20the%20first%20popular%20anime%20television%20series%20in%201963.%20Contrary%20to%20popular%20belief,%20Atom%20was%20not%20the%20first%20anime%20series%20broadcast%20in%20Japan;%20that%20honor%20falls%20to%20Otogi%20Manga%20Calendar,%20which%20began%20broadcasting%20in%201962.%20The%20first%20non-series%20anime%20broadcasted%20was%20Three%20Tales&source=bl&ots=6u-PjFliz6&sig=mjOei314wQVaAWeC70IuuYt0I4k&hl=id&sa=X&ei=eHyIU5T9LdK58gWgoYFY&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Mighty%20Atom%20became%20the%20first%20popular%20anime%20television%20series%20in%201963.%20Contrary%20to%20popular%20belief,%20Atom%20was%20not%20the%20first%20anime%20series%20broadcast%20in%20Japan;%20that%20honor%20falls%20to%20Otogi%20Manga%20Calendar,%20which%20began%20broadcasting%20in%201962.%20The%20first%20non-series%20anime%20broadcasted%20was%20Three%20Tales&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Films were released in cinemas, not broadcast, but there were animated films, Japanese TV animations in the 50s were commercials or interstitials, Otogi Manga calendar was a TV animation, but not the first anime series, Astro Boy has been first because, it was the first regularly broadcasted anime series.

Answer (score -3):

According to [the Trivia section on IMDb page of "Future Boy Conan"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077013/trivia/?ref_=tt_trv_trv), it says it was the first.

> First animated series to air on Japanese Public TV, NHK.

Comment: Incorrect.  There were series airing in the 60's, like the other answer states.  Other shows like Gigantor, Astro Boy came out around the same time.  IMDB can be full of it at times.

Comment: however the trivia section (which you don't quote or link to) just says *"First animated series to air on Japanese Public TV, NHK."* while your link only says the year. while [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Boy_Conan) confirms the year and date of when the series aired a [previous answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/10021/1587) also has links to wikipedia with series that predate this. it's possible the trivia is actually saying that it was the first anime series to air on NHK but *NOT* the first anime series to air